# Couldn't find include 'GObject-2.0.gir'

Tags: ubuntu, glib, gobject, gobject-introspection

I am trying to install totem-pl-parser-3.10.7 on my Ubuntu 14.04, and after the `autogen.sh` + `configure` end successfully, I build with `make`. But I receive the following error:

```
Couldn't find include 'GObject-2.0.gir' (search path: ['.', '.', '/usr/share/gnome-fallback/gir-1.0', '/usr/share/gnome/gir-1.0', '/usr/local/share/gir-1.0', '/usr/share/gir-1.0', '/usr/share/gir-1.0', '/usr/share/gir-1.0', '/usr/share/gir-1.0'])
```

Searching on google the possible causes, It came out that `gobject-introspection` package was installed after `libglib-2.0-dev`, and so the `.gir` repositories could not be found properly.

Also, I removed `libglib-2.0-dev` (`apt remove --purge`) and reinstalled it, but the error still comes out the same.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to install the `libgirepository1.0-dev` package.

See [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=GObject-2.0.gir&mode=exactfilename&suite=yakkety&arch=any).

Comment: THANK YOU! This solved Vala error I been fighting, pasted should it help others search: "error: Package 'GObject-2.0' not found in specified Vala API directories or GObject-Introspection GIR directories"