# vala Package 'xxxx' not found

Tags: ubuntu, compilation, vala

system information.

```
⭕ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS"

⭕ valac --version
Vala 0.48.6
```

compile error.

```
⭕ valac --pkg gtk+-3.0  --pkg posix list-exec.vala
error: Package `glib-2.0' not found in specified Vala API directories or GObject-Introspection GIR directories
error: Package `gobject-2.0' not found in specified Vala API directories or GObject-Introspection GIR directories
error: Package `gtk+-3.0' not found in specified Vala API directories or GObject-Introspection GIR directories
error: Package `posix' not found in specified Vala API directories or GObject-Introspection GIR directories
Compilation failed: 4 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

most development packages had been installed.

```
⭕ pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0
-pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/include.......

⭕ pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0
-I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86......

⭕ pkg-config --cflags --libs gobject-2.0
-I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-l......
```

can not found posix package.

```
⭕ pkg-config --cflags --libs posix
Package posix was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `posix.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'posix' found
```

vapi directory here.

```
⭕ l /usr/share/vala/vapi/
gcalc-2.deps  gcalc-2.vapi  gci-1.deps  gci-1.vapi
```

So how can I fixed those?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the PPA has its own package for VAPIs: [valac-0.48-vapi](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/hirsute/amd64/valac-0.48-vapi/0.48.11-1)

`ls /usr/share/vala-0.48/vapi/ | grep -P \^\(gtk\|glib\|gobject\|posix\)` should show something like this:

```
glib-2.0.vapi
gobject-2.0.deps
gobject-2.0.vapi
gtk+-3.0.deps
gtk+-3.0.vapi
gtk4.deps
gtk4-unix-print.deps
gtk4-unix-print.vapi
gtk4.vapi
posix.vapi
```

Comment: Thanks. It so stranger, `valac` depends on `valac-0.48-vapi`, but in my system, the valac-0.48-vapi package not here.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar compile error, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42486094/1654116) solved it for me:

```
sudo apt install libgirepository1.0-dev
```

Comment: This answer is useful for solving `Dependency "gobject-introspection-1.0" not found, tried pkgconfig and cmake`